# bashrc not found on MacOS Monterey version 12.0

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, zshrc, macos-monterey

I am using MacOS Monterey version 12.0

I checked in root directory, I don't have `.bashrc` and `.bashprofile`, but my system is using `.zshrc` and `.zprofile`

I am getting error that

> ./bin/temp.sh: line 3: /Users/xyz/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Code of `temp.sh` file at line 3 :

> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> source ~/.bashrc.  # This line is causing error

Temporarily, I replaced this line with below and it is working

> #!/usr/bin/env zsh
>
> source ~/.zshrc.  # This is working fine !!

From searching over few answers and posts, I got to know that Mac systems are transitioning to `zsh` from `bash`, because `zsh` is improved version of `bash`

Can anyone tell me proper solution of routing `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile` commands to fetch internally `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` ?

what will be best solution so that same script file can run on both systems having `zsh` and `bash` shells?

Comment: If you don't use bash as your interactive shell, you probably don't need a .bashrc or .bash_profile. The real question is, what is this `temp.sh` script, and why is it trying to source your .bashrc?

Comment: Trying to run code written for zsh with bash, or vis versa, is not going to go well for anything but the simplest, sh compatible, scripts.

Comment: *because zsh is improved version of bash* zsh isn't any kind of version of bash; it's a completely different shell.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but note that "_Mac systems are transitioning to zsh from bash_" is probably not "_because zsh is improved version of bash_" but rather because Apple doesn't like the GPL license... So for your scripts, **use whichever you like better**, not what Apple's lawyers prefer.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `temp.sh` is file which does some setup by adding some env variables, so needed a solution which can work with `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` both

Comment: Standard practice is to write two separate scripts, and let the user pick which is appropriate for their shell. You wouldn't expect the same source file to work for Javascript, Python, and Rust, would you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your script to use `zsh`, you will need to replace the first line which calls your shell, to make it call `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
```

And then make sure your script isn't using anything specific to `bash`, or adapt the script to replace tit's "bashisms" with the zsh-specific equivalents.

Alternatively, you could also just create the file you need to `source` with the content you want. The real question is why is your script trying to source `.bashrc`? Which variables/functions/whatever does your script want to initialize from there?

Comment: How to write `.sh` file which can work with `.bashrc' and '.zshrc' both? Is there any conditioning can we make based on which shell is running in mac os?